# How to search users in Microsoft Graph SDK with C#?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In my C# application, I am using Microsoft Graph SDK with Azure AD implementation.

Please suggest me how to search users in my organisations (global contacts) based on search parameters . 
For example , if "Raj" is the search parameter, I should be able to get all users with their name contains "Raj" or email address contains "Raj".
I found this method to get all users - "graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();". but, with this method limited response, I am not getting what exactly I want to search.

Thanks,
Shashidhar

Answer (score 15):

Adding to the previous answer: to accomplish this through the Graph C# SDK, use the Filter() method:

```
graphClient.Users.Request().Filter("startsWith(displayName, 'k')").GetAsync()
```

You can use other methods on the request to customize the request, e.g. Select(), etc.

Answer (score 4):

According to your description, I assume you want to search the users by using the search parameters.

Based on [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter), we can currently search only message and person collections.

And I have tried the filter query parameter, the parameter is currently  not supported the `contains` operator from [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter). So if you want to search the user with name or the email address, we can use the `startswith` operator only.Like this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'k') or startswith(mail,'k')`

It will find the user's diplayName or mail which is start with the `k`

Answer (score 1):

```
 var queryOptions = new List<Option>() 
            { 
                new QueryOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual") ,
                new QueryOption("$search", "\"displayName:fis\"") 
            };

            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<GraphServiceClient>();

            var users = await graphServiceClient.Users
                .Request(queryOptions)
                .WithAppOnly()
                .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Need at least a brief explanation.